# MongoDB update by aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I want to add one filed to document as a result of aggregation.

Aggregation returns multiple items, but update updates only one.

**Why only one?**

Here is my code

```
var maxCount = db.technology.aggregate({
     $group: {
         _id:"$_id", 
          stackMax: {
             $max:"$stackTimeLine.statistics.count"}
          }
     });

 while(maxCount.hasNext()) {
    var item=maxCount.next();  
    db.technology.update(
         {_id:item._id}, 
         {$set: {'stackTimeLine.latest':item.stackMax[0]}}
    );
 }
```

Result:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Comment: If you want multiple update you need add multi:true. db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     
     multi: true
        }
) Try: db.technology.update(
         {_id:item._id}, 
         {$set: {'stackTimeLine.latest':item.stackMax[0]}}, {'multi':true}
    );

Comment: I tried, no luck. Moreover every update should update only one entry. No "multi" required.

Comment: Your aggregation doesn't really do anything. Then you are setting a field to its current value, so it's a no-op. Can you describe what you're trying to add to the documents?

Comment: I want to take max value from field **count** in **statistics** array and assign that value to new field in enclosing document. Aggregation works fine and returns expected results, but update not

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation result is not a cursor, you cant use `hasNext()` and `next()` on it. for example, my aggregation output is

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : [ 
                "8"
            ],
            "count" : 474
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : [ 
                "vista"
            ],
            "count" : 414
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : [ 
                "xp"
            ],
            "count" : 5112
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Then I use `forEach()` on `aggregationResult.result`

```
var aggregationResult = db.Collection.aggregate(
[
   {$group : {_id : '$ps.d.Name', count : { $sum: 1 }}}
]);

aggregationResult.result.forEach(function(item)
{
    print(item);
})
```

You can update your item instead of `print()` in `forEach()` function body

Comment: I put _print(item._id+' '+item.stackMax[0])_ after _var item = ..._.  All entries were printed, but updated only 1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answer of [that guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095122/mongodb-aggregate-error-typeerror-cannot-call-method-foreach-of-undefine)  solution found.

In mongo shell aggregation result has no property **result**

Previous answer works fine if remove **result** from forEach